# combine data from two different strings in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have two strings:

```
a ='hellowww'
b ='world'
```

**Expected Output**

```
c = 'hweolrllodwww'
```

**My code**:

```
for x,y in zip(a,b):
    print(x,y)
```

Its not working in my case.

**Note** : Length of two strings ,may not be same.

Comment: `from itertools import zip_longest; c = ''.join(s + t for s, t in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=''))` or `c = ''.join(s for tup in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue='') for s in tup)`

Answer (score 4):

`zip` stops when the shortest iterable is traversed. You can use `itertool` module instead via `chain` and `zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

res = ''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue='')))

# 'hweolrllodwww'
```